# How to stop outside rainwater from coming in under the wall and through the concrete floor of my garage conversion?

Tags: repair, water, walls, concrete, flooring

I have got a problem with an attached garage converted den in a 1978 built brick home.

The heavy spring rains are redirected to the two year old perforated drain system on the side of the house approximately 10-15 feet away and slopes down into the swail on top of the drain system.

However when it rains for days and days the water is not running fast enough and sits in puddles on top of the drain system and takes days some times to disperse. I also have another drain next to the driveway that begins at the outside wall where the door used to be and runs down the edge of the driveway and it works well.

So here are the two problems:

1. The floor of the garage conversion den, which is lower than the house, is seeping water to the surface and cracking the floor and popping bits of concrete up and making holes that seep water.
2. Under the wall where the door used to be is letting water through. The spot the water leaks through is where the driveway butts up against the wall; and the edges of the driveway in the corners where the outside brick wall begins. The walk way to the front door is also cracking and it leads right to the edge of the driveway in the corner where the siding and brick meet. I don't know if you can get the picture. This allows water to get under the concrete and under the wall. I put another layer of concrete up against the wall on the outside and sloped it but the corners again are the problem and I suspect the end of the slope down that meets the old driveway is letting water get through. I need a new driveway but can't afford one right now.

Is there a product I can put on the outside siding/driveway and corners to seal it up. And is there a product I can put on the floor to keep the pressure of the water from breaking through?

Comment: Sounds like your drainage system may have a clog. When is the last time you cleaned it out? You may be able to DIY with a plumbing snake and garden hose.

Comment: Locking because if asked today this would be closed as "product recommendation"

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me that the first thing you should do is rebuild your drainage system.  If you still feel that once the system has been adequately rebuilt, or if this is not a feasible option for you, then there are various [floor water sealing products](http://www.homedepot.com/Building-Materials-Concrete-Cement-Masonry-Additives-Sealants/h_d1/N-5yc1vZarzy/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&Nu=P_PARENT_ID&langId=-1&storeId=10051) out there you can use.